# How to do a recursive call for finding the sum of elements in an array of points?

Tags: javascript

The idea is to find the mid point of a bezeir curve. Following is the De Casteljau's algorithm for finding the midpoint of a curve with four points.

How can I implement such an algorithm in javascript using recursion?

Following is the four starting points. From here we start the algorithm and through recursion we arrive the tip of the tree.

```
(0, 0)
      \
       (1/2, 0) --> this node is calculated as follows [(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2]
      /        \
(1, 0)          (3/4, 1/4)
      \        /          \
       (1, 1/2)            (3/4, 1/2)
      /        \          /
(1, 1)          (3/4, 3/4)
      \        /
       (1/2, 1)
      /
(0, 1)
```

for example the sample input of points will be like this

```
const points = [[0,2], [4,5], [6,7], [3,8]]

output = [3,5]

// so the output will be just an array of two numbers for eg: [3,5] (just a rough figure for demo) which represents the midpoint of the above four points obtained by the above algorithm.
```

This is what I've tried. But it is entirely wrong. Can someone help?

```
    const mid = (array) => {
      if (array.length === 1) 
        return array
      else {
        array.map(point => [point[0] + point[1] + point[2]])
      }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Remember each node is calculated as follows [(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2]. i.e., by taking the average of similar coordinates of two adjacent points.= .

**UPDATE**

The second code suggested by Nina Scholz works fine.

But I want to extend it further. Ninas code returns the first midpoint. But I want to extend it to find more points as illustrated below.

[image]

Comment: do you want only integer values? if not the result is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and get a single pair.

This approach takes only integer values.

```js
const
    getB = array => {
        if (array.length === 1) return array[0];

        const result = [];

        for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            result.push([Math.floor((array[i - 1][0] + array[i][0]) / 2), Math.floor((array[i - 1][1] + array[i][1]) / 2)]);
        }        

        return getB(result);
    },
    points = [[0, 2], [4, 5], [6, 7], [3, 8]];

console.log(getB(points));
```

Same approach without using integer values.

```js
const
    getB = array => {
        if (array.length === 1) return array[0];

        const result = [];

        for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            result.push([(array[i - 1][0] + array[i][0]) / 2, (array[i - 1][1] + array[i][1]) / 2]);
        }        

        return getB(result);
    },
    points = [[0, 2], [4, 5], [6, 7], [3, 8]];

console.log(getB(points));
```

Comment: Hi. I like your approach. Can you please extend this further? For example if I want to find multiple points we can further extend this ... I've updated the question. –

Comment: I've provided an illustration regarding this. Can you update your code for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `reduce` and `map` which will work for the sub-arrays of any sizes assuming you they are of the same length.

```js
const points = [[0,2], [4,5], [6,7], [3,8]]

function calc(data) {
  if (data.length == 1) return data;

  const points = data.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
    if (a[i + 1]) r.push(e.map((n, j) => (n + a[i + 1][j]) / e.length))
    return r;
  }, [])

  return calc(points)
}

const result = calc(points);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good use for the Reduce array method.

```
     array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            return [(acc[0] + cur[0])/2, (acc[1] + cur[1])/2]
        })
```

Comment: this take the last value as input for the next iteration. the question is about crearting new arrays with one item less then given until only one item (pair) exists.